# pass value from one jframe to other jframe?

Tags: java, user-interface

i created two classes one class is just like form the other class is main class and having jmenu and jinternal frames i want to print the input from the form class on the jinternal frame but i cannot understand how i recall the jinternalframe in the form classes, please guide me in this regard or any hint or some piece of code or tutorial that can help me here is code of both the classes. Moreover both classes are working fine .

```
JTextArea text;
     static int openFrameCount = 0;
    public form(){


           super("Insert Form");
        Container panel=getContentPane();
        JPanel  cc    = new JPanel();
        cc.setLayout(new  FlowLayout());


        JButton b=new JButton("print");
     b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140,50));
     b.setBounds(1000,500,350,50);
       cc.add(b);
       .......................................................


        JLabel label1=new JLabel(" Question"+(++openFrameCount));

        cc.add(label1);
        text=new JTextArea();
                text.setLineWrap(true);
        text.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        text.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750,50));
        text.setBounds(80, 60,750,50);
        cc.add(text);
         JLabel symbol=new JLabel("Selection for Option?");
         symbol.setBounds(200, 120,1000,100);
 cc.add(symbol);

  ..................................................



          JLabel op4=new JLabel("4th Option?");
           JTextArea otext4=new  JTextArea();
          otext4.setLineWrap(true);
        otext4.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        otext4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750,50));
        otext4.setBounds(10, 40,700,30);
            cc.add( op4 ) ;
          cc.add( otext4 ) ;






          cc.revalidate();
 validate();

  ............................................................  

        }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
     if ( e.getSource() == b1 ){  

    }

}
```

}
and the second class of jinternalframe is

```
public class Desktop1 extends JFrame
                               implements ActionListener {
    Desktop p=new Desktop();
    JDesktopPane desktop;

static int openFrameCount = 0;
    public Desktop1() {
        super("InternalFrameDemo");

        //Make the big window be indented 50 pixels from each edge
        //of the screen.
        int inset = 50;
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(inset, inset,
                  screenSize.width  - inset*2,
                  screenSize.height - inset*2);

        //Set up the GUI.
        desktop = new JDesktopPane(); //a specialized layered pane

        createFrame(); //create first "window"
        setContentPane(desktop);
        setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());

        //Make dragging a little faster but perhaps uglier.
        desktop.setDragMode(JDesktopPane.OUTLINE_DRAG_MODE);
    }

    protected JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        //Set up the lone menu.


       .................................................



        return menuBar;
    }

    //React to menu selections.
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ("new".equals(e.getActionCommand())) { //new
            createFrame();
        } 

        ............................................
        }
    }


    class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

        static final int xPosition = 30, yPosition = 30;
        public MyInternalFrame() {
            super("IFrame #" + (++openFrameCount), true, // resizable
                    true, // closable
                    true, // maximizable
                    true);// iconifiable
            setSize(700, 700);
            // Set the window's location.
            setLocation(xPosition * openFrameCount, yPosition
                    * openFrameCount);
        }
    }
    //Create a new internal frame.
    protected void createFrame() {
        Desktop1.MyInternalFrame frame = new Desktop1.MyInternalFrame();


        JPanel panel=new JPanel();//to add scrollbar in jinternalpane insert jpanel
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);//set background color of jinternal frame
        JScrollPane scrollBar=new JScrollPane(panel,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        frame.add(scrollBar);

        frame.setVisible(true); 


        desktop.add(frame);
        try {
            frame.setSelected(true);
           frame.setMaximum(true);
        } catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {}
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Desktop1 d=new Desktop1();
         d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        d.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

i want to know hint about the work that come in this part of code to pass the value of form to internal frame when i click on print button

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
         if ( e.getSource() == b1 ){  

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to pass some text to your InternalFrame class on the button click from the main form.
Modify your createFrame() method to accept a String value
e.g-

```
protected void createFrame(String value){
 //..your code    
}
```

and when you call your InternalFrame class, pass this value to its constructor. e.g-

```
 Desktop1.MyInternalFrame frame = new Desktop1.MyInternalFrame(value);
```

Parameterised constructor will solve your problem. Modify your InternalFrame constructor 
e.g-

```
public MyInternalFrame(String value){
 //..use this value    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just call the constructor and pass the value

```
ClassName(parameter)
```